# Happy Thanksgiving!

Tags: discussion

Happy Thanksgiving to all US folks.

My question: How do you spend your Thanksgiving day?

My wife and I host Thanksgiving for our extended family each year. Everyone comes over to eat, drink, talk, and sometimes watch football.

This year, we have 25 people coming. My wife and I spent yesterday getting everything ready to go. This morning, the turkeys are in the oven and we are off.

Enjoy!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanksgiving_(United_States)

Comment: 25 people? You're crazy! That's a lot of prep and space :). We're visiting relatives, only 15 or so total -- assuming the snow and ice hold off... Might be a lot fewer.

Comment: @enderland - it is a lot of prep, but we enjoy it. We don't have a lot of space, so we have tables set up in the dining room, kitchen, and even the living room. It's a beautiful day in New England, so looks like we'll work off some of the turkey with touch football in the back yard.

Comment: :) We got snowed out. "Snow/sleet/ice mix" and multi-hour drive for the first winter snowfall of the year... sounds fun!

Comment: We're now past Thanksgiving, Black Friday, Cyber Monday, and Giving Tuesday, so I'm going to call that a wrap and close this now.

Comment: Happy Thanksgiving @JoeStrazzere :) hope you have another big and fun gathering with your Family. Cheers.

Comment: @DarkCygnus - thank you! Actually this year is going to be different from the rest. I'm dealing with a medical issue at the moment, and had my first treatment this week. I'll be avoiding crowds until my treatments are completed (probably by year end). So we had to tell everyone that we wouldn't be able to host Thanksgiving this year. Fortunately, my brother took it over this time, so the family can still gather and enjoy themselves without us. This is the first time in many, many years we have had to do this. Hopefully, it will be the last.

Answer (score 5):

> How do you spend your Thanksgiving day?

Working and once again lamenting that, as a European, the only way Thanksgiving affects me is by interrupting the US' television broadcast schedule, forcing me to go without my weekly episode(s). :|

But Happy Thanksgiving to you and yours I guess. ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing there are a few European holidays that aren't celebrated in the US, so you can feel good about that.

Comment: It's ok; *Big Bang Theory* should be back next week. :-)

Comment: Reading this again I realise that my attempt at "disgruntled foreigner sarcasm" may not have been apparent to all. Rest assured that I wrote this with tongue firmly in cheek and that I don't begrudge anyone their holiday. :)

Answer (score 4):

Greeting to you and your family, Joe!

Happy Thanksgiving, folks!

We Indians, have no idea what Thanksgiving is.  Well, maybe the folks in the US, are getting ready for Christmas.

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What are you talking about? Indians partook in the very first Thanksgiving!

Comment: @JimG. Is it?  Maybe they forgot to inform me!   On a serious note, no one knows about it here, leave alone celebrating it :)

Comment: @Dawny33 - Jim was joking, since it was Native Americans (sometimes called Indians) who took part in the first Thanksgiving. I live near the location where it took place. It's a nice holiday for many - college students often return home for the occasion, lots of family join, and there are no gits - just lots of food.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Ha ha, yeah it took some time for me to get it  :D   But, I let the comment as is!

Answer (score 1):

Most years I have a choice between a quiet family thanksgiving -- not always with my own family -- or a huge gathering of APO alumni, mostly from my school and mostly from my time period (though others also attend and some of the kids are now old enough that they're attending on their own behalf.)

One of the tricks we've developed for the alumni mob is that dinner is pot-luck with each family assigned a *color* of food for their contribution. That can be interpreted creatively -- when I got purple I made a proper Red Velvet cake, which uses beets -- but it's sufficient to ensure against duplication of dishes, and to encourage folks to try new recipies.

Comment: Nice! Sounds colorful...

Comment: A real Red Velvet cake uses beets? TIL... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_velvet_cake